# Calcular horas por cada trabajador

Tags: mysql

Muy buenos días estimados, tomé una consulta de ejemplo de StackOverflow e intente adaptarla una consulta que me permita mostrar los registros de marcas de cada empleado, por ejemplo: Entrada(hora_entrada_1), hora_Salida1(almuerzo) hora_entrada_2 (hora regreso almuerzo), salida fin de hora laboral, con el propósito de conocer los minutos tardes en el ingreso y hora de almuerzo. El problema radica que me muestra duplicada cada registro según fecha y no me los ordena según la columna que corresponde, le e agregado un `where` al final de la consulta pero a sido imposible lograrlo, la estructura de la tabla seria así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto la consulta que tengo:

```
 select 
        h.idregistros,
        h.idempleado,
        h.status,
        h.fechahorareg,
        ce1.fechahorareg as hora_entrada_1,
        cs1.fechahorareg as hora_salida_1,
        ce2.fechahorareg as hora_entrada_2,
        cs2.fechahorareg as hora_salida_2,
    
        DATE_FORMAT(timediff(convert(TIME_FORMAT(cs1.fechahorareg,'%H:%i:%s'), time),
            convert(DATE_FORMAT(ce2.fechahorareg,'%H:%i:%s'), time)),'%H:%i:%s') as diferencia_HoraAlmuerzo,
    
      DATE_FORMAT(timediff(convert(TIME_FORMAT(ce1.fechahorareg,'%H:%i:%s'), time),
       convert(DATE_FORMAT('2022-01-01 08:01:00','%H:%i:%s'), time)),'%H:%i:%s') as diferencia_Entradamañana
        
    
        from tbregistros h
        
        left join tbregistros ce1
        
            on ce1.idempleado = h.idempleado 
        and ce1.status = 'ENTRADA'
        
        and ce1.fechahorareg = (SELECT fechahorareg
                        from tbregistros c
                        where c.idempleado = ce1.idempleado
                        and c.fechahorareg = ce1.fechahorareg
                        and c.status = ce1.status
                        
                        ORDER BY fechahorareg asc
                        limit 1)
                
        left join tbregistros cs1
            on cs1.idempleado = h.idempleado  
            and cs1.status = 'SALIDA'
            
            and cs1.fechahorareg = (SELECT  fechahorareg
                            from tbregistros c
                            where c.idempleado = cs1.idempleado
                            and c.fechahorareg = cs1.fechahorareg
                            and c.status = cs1.status
                            ORDER BY fechahorareg asc
                            limit 1)
    
        left join tbregistros ce2 
        on ce2.idempleado = h.idempleado   
        and ce2.status = 'ENTRADA'
    
        and ce2.fechahorareg = (SELECT  fechahorareg
                        from tbregistros c
                        where c.idempleado = ce2.idempleado
                        and c.fechahorareg = ce2.fechahorareg
                        and c.status = ce2.status
                        ORDER BY fechahorareg desc
                        limit 1)
        left join tbregistros cs2
        on cs2.idempleado = h.idempleado 
        and cs2.status = 'SALIDA'
        and cs2.fechahorareg = (SELECT  fechahorareg
                        from tbregistros c
                        where c.idempleado = cs2.idempleado
                        and c.fechahorareg = cs2.fechahorareg
                        and c.status = cs2.status
                        ORDER BY fechahorareg desc
                        limit 1)
                    
        
    where h.idempleado=ce2.idempleado and h.idregistros=ce2.idregistros and h.idempleado=ce1.idempleado   and h.idregistros=ce1.idregistros and h.idempleado = cs2.idempleado/*  and ce1.idregistros=h.idregistros and cs2.idempleado=h.idempleado and cs2.idregistros=h.idregistros*/
    order by idempleado ASC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]